# Нужна ли запятая и каким правилом её оправдать?

Tags: пунктуация

> Мы скорбно, молча поднялись наверх, пошли по краю большого бассейна, а
>   тут нам навстречу «усталые ребята» – тренеры *(ЗАПЯТАЯ ЛЬ?)* и вместо
>   приветствия говорят: «Раздевайтесь давайте. Полезайте-ка в воду,
>   поплавайте». Мы опешили. В смысле? Как так? С дельфинами? У меня и
>   купальника-то нет… Они отвечают: «Сейчас всё придумаем. Пошли».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Мы скорбно, молча поднялись наверх, пошли по краю большого бассейна, (2) а тут нам навстречу «усталые ребята» – тренеры, (3) и вместо приветствия (они) говорят...

**Здесь три предложения:** предложение (2) неполное эллиптического типа, предложение (3) также неполное (пропущено сказуемое). Связь бессоюзная и союзная, перед союзом И запятая ставится.

Answer (score 2):

А мне кажется, что указанная запятая не нужна. Вторая часть предложения по смыслу (как я вижу) выглядит так:
*а тут нам навстречу [**идут**] «усталые ребята» – тренеры **и** вместо приветствия **говорят**...*
Обычные однородные сказуемые, просто одно пропущено.

**Дополнение**

*Я как рубеж запомню вечер:

декабрь, безогненная мгла,

я хлеб в руке домой несла,

и вдруг соседка* [идет] *мне навстречу.*
О. Берггольц

Глагол "идет" только подразумевается.

Comment: А что связывает союз И, ведь в предложении  (2) глагол "идут" отсутствует. И паузу  перед союзом И желательно сделать.

Comment: Нельзя говорить о союзе между двумя однородными членами, если один из них только подразумеватся, хотя можно подумать над вариантом считать однородными сказуемыми *навстречу* и *говорят*.